# Launch a command on a server while a job has been launched with cron

Tags: server, cron, command, resources

I am wondering if I could launch a command on a server using the server terminal without interfering with my cron job that was launched automatically 1 hour away ? The server is an ubuntu, distant, with few resources, and I am communicating with it on PuTTY.

And second asking, do you know a command to check the amount of resources used by my running cron ? This is the command I would launch on the server right now.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Valentine

PS : for the moment, I didn't try anything because it is really important that my process running with a cron succeed.

Comment: A question should only have a single question.  As for your first question, you are running a cron job hourly? What command are you wanting to run manually? How is it you think this will interfere with the cronjob?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the two questions, I had to add the second because actually the command I would like to launch on the server is the object of my second question. So I am not able to tell you exactly which is the command but I want it to check the resources used by my cron job. The cron job is running all Mondays (except for this week). I haven't experience so much the working of cron jobs so I don't know if something could interfer with a running cron job. This is the object of my first question. Sorry if it was confused.

Comment: We won’t know either. However, in general if a cron job runs you won’t interfere unless you act on the same files, databases, networks, or devices it needs.